# Fetching all Tokens that belong to a Minting Policy

Tags: plutus

Is there a way to programmatically get all the `TokenName`s belonging to a `CurrencySymbol` with Plutus?

Comment: Do you mean all the `TokenName`s ever minted by a policy, or within a specified scope?

Comment: @MitchellTurner I mean all `TokenName`s ever minted by a policy. But I've come to realize that it may only be possible using an Oracle. I may be wrong tho.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Using ghci in Plutus repo I'll show you how. I will use fully qualified functions for clarity, and don't forget to `:set -XOverloadedStrings`.

Plutus observes all tokens in an output using txOutValue of [TxOut](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Api.html#t:TxOut). To define our own [Value](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Api.html#t:Value) we can do (taken from [PPP Lecture#5](https://youtu.be/SsaVjSsPPcg?t=491)):

```
> let v = Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.singleton "a8ff" "ABC" 7 <> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Ada.lovelaceValueOf 42 <> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.singleton "a8ff" "XYZ" 100
> v
Value (Map [(,Map [("",42)]),(a8ff,Map [("ABC",7),("XYZ",100)])])
```

To filter by [CurrencySymbol](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Value.html#v:currencySymbol) we can do:

```
> PlutusTx.AssocMap.keys $ Data.Maybe.fromJust $ PlutusTx.AssocMap.lookup "a8ff" (Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.getValue v)
["ABC","XYZ"]
```

This gives you `TokenName`s for `CurrencySymbol` a8ff. Ada's `CurrencySymbol` of `""` has been filtered out.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot have multiple TokenNames belonging to the same CurrencySymbol. Together, TokenName & CurrencySymbol can form an asset class. Once this asset class is formed, it can be wrapped in a Value list.

The reason that TokenName & CurrencySymbol must be 1-1 is that the CurrencySymbol is the hash of the monitary policy script used to validate the Token.

If you had multiple tokens with different TokenNames using the same CurrencySymbol, they would all use the same monitary policy, and that would create some issues with validation.

Comment: @Aoaddeola, you can edit and delete your own comments ;-)

Comment: Thanks @gRebel :)

Comment: According to lecture #5 of the PPP, Lars demonstrated on the command line how to combine tokens using the Value.singleton function... `singleton "a8ff" "ABC" 7 <> lovelaceValueOf 42 <> singleton "a8ff" "XYZ" 100` thereby producing: `Value (Map [(,Map [("",42)]),(a8ff,Map [("ABC",7),("XYZ",100)])])`... Hence, I fail to see how multiple TokenNames can't map to a single CurrencySymbol/Monetary Policy.

Comment: Mmmm I see the confusion. Value is simply a container for a token or multiple tokens of different types(as shown above). It is different from the CurrencySymbol. In the above example, each one of these singleton tokens have their own TokenName and  CurrencySymbol. They are then grouped using the <> operator into a Value.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your explanation. But the fact remains that both `TokenName`s "XYZ" and "ABC" belong to the same `CurrencySymbol` "a8ff"

Comment: The same name is used by Lars because he was being slightly lazy here. When the singleton function is used on the blockchain, there will be a check to ensure that the Currency Symbol does not already exist. In the example above its okay to have the same CurrencySymbol because these functions are not being executed on the blockchain.

Comment: I'd like you to demonstrate what you mean by "there will be a check to ensure that the Currency Symbol does not already exist". You can find me on discord with same user account (aoaddeola) :)

Comment: This is an incorrect answer: there is not a 1-1 relationship between CurrencySymbol and TokenName, in fact on the contrary one can have an arbitrary number of tokens ( TokenName ) operating within the same CurrencySymbol (policy).

Comment: You sure? I need some more info! I want to know the answer for sure

Comment: Alright I'm a fool. The snippet of code provided by Aoddeola pretty much sums it up.